# On Xcode4.2 memory management, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, xcode4.2

Assuming a **new project with ARC enabled** is created

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

and the following declaration

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *classDescription;
```

Why would

```
@synthesize classDescription;
```

error out with

```
"Existing ivar 'classDescription' for unsafe_unretained propery 'classDescription must be _unsafe_unretained"
```

**I thought that with Version 4.2 of Xcode, no retains, releases are needed.** Is this not correct?

Please clarify

Comment: Does ARC make the `copy` modifier on an NSString property obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it a `strong` property so that ARC knows it should retain the object.

Comment: This solves the issue, however i wonder if this is referenced in some guide online somewhere? Please link

Answer (score 0):

No retains/releases are needed if you are using Automatic Reference Counting.  Is this an existing project or new project?  New projects should have ARC enabled by default.

Comment: It is a new project. With ARC enabled. This is why i found this to be strange to see this error

Answer (score 0):

If your project was made before Xcode 4.2, then you can enable it by going to Build Settings, search for Objective-C++ Automatic Reference Counting and tick the box.

Comment: This is a brand new project with ARC enabled